# How to fix a ColdFusion app that runs much slower with sandbox security on?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

Recently we upgraded to ColdFusion 11 Enterprise and noticed that the full-fledged sandbox security tends to have a way bigger overhead than the Standard edition (CF10).

What can one do to make an existing CF app perform well with sandbox security?

Comment: Thought of posting this to my old blog but I think posting here will be more beneficial to the community and the search engines.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would you want to run an application with sandbox security when performance matters? Isn't overhead something one would expect when running on an additionally secured environment?

Comment: @Alex they both matter for us.  I did try asking if we are permitted to run them without the sandbox security on, but the answer was no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my findings so far:

- install [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) by adding `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8701 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false` to CF Admin's JVM Arguments.  Learn how to use it and pay special attention to the CPU Snapshot & Hotspot tab.  http://boncode.blogspot.ca/2010/04/cf-java-using-free-visualvm-tool-to.html.  FYI CF Server Monitor in the Enterprise edition is utterly useless because its memory/performance profiling overhead is way too big to be viable for a live production server, and it doesn't perform well under load to give you any useful data of what could be going wrong.
- Disable IPv6, and add `[serverip] [serverip]` to the OS's hostfile to speed up the default DNS reverse proxy lookup on creating new physical DB connection by [Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html). See: [On Linux, Java issues reverse DNS lookups when a socket is opened. Why, and how can I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087634/on-linux-java-issues-reverse-dns-lookups-when-a-socket-is-opened-why-and-how) (FYI, Windows is affected to)
- remove as much `<cfmodule>` and `<cfinclude>` as possible as they will end up with many `java.io.File.canRead()` and `java.io.File.exists()` which will  stress the disk IO under load.  Even SSD suffers under load.  I have tried Trusted Cache and it does not help.  Instead, try using cached CFC's in `application` scope and make sure the code are thread safe and local-var'ed.
- eliminate the use of `<cfinterface>`, inheritance with `extends`, and `getMetaData()` as much as possible as they will eventually calls `java.io.File.lastModified()` which will stress the disk IO under load. [Bug?](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4173282)
- eliminate the use of `access="package"` as it will end up with many `java.security.AccessController.checkPermission` calls.
- less objects per request the better, as each object instantiation has a higher cost with the extra `java.security.AccessController.checkPermission` call.